# How to properly check time elapsed for an Android game written in Kotlin?

Tags: android, time, kotlin

I am developing a game for a school project. I would like to include idle "missions" - where an action is started and after a certain amount of time elapsed, the mission would be over. How would I go about this, and keep the end user from being able to trick the game by setting the phone time forward? Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

You could start a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer). This example is from the Android reference documentation (converted to Kotlin) and creates a timer counting down from 30 seconds to zero and calls the onTick function every second:

```
object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        textView.setText("Seconds remaining: ${millisUntilFinished / 1000}.")
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        textView.setText("Done!")
    }
}.start()
```

You can put this code in a function, for example in your onCreate.